# From XML to object

Tags: .net, asp.net, xml, parsing

I would like to define an asp.net page from xml, then parse/render it by calling a command name. Just like they do in Flex. Does someone has an idea how to do that?

Like for example, from XML:

```
<button onClick="DoJavascript()" text="Submit"/>
<gridview ......./>
```

To parse:

`<asp:button runat="server" onClick="DoJavascript()" text="Submit"/>
<asp:gridview runat="server" ......./>`

Comment: Can you explain your problem a little more?  This is very unclear.

Comment: Sorry. The basic idea is to adapt a xml document to a page, with the possibility to add asp.net controls with valid propteries and events to check up it through the libraries. adapting xml to html is trivial.

Answer (score 1):

You could try XSLT, that's in general what is used to transform XML.

Answer (score 0):

In your case data and objects are synonymous. Basically you are taking your top XML and spit it out into ASP.Net pages. I don't have enough experience with ASP.Net to tell you how you would go ahead and now parse the code programmatically into a Page object, but, if you wanna do the transformation and let ASP.Net parse/render the aspx, this is all you need.